# Is there a difference in entity framework order?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm running into some speed issues in my project and it seems like the primary cause it calls to the database using entity framework. Every time I call the database, it is always done as
`database.Include(...).Where(...)`
and I'm wondering if that is different than
`database.Where(...).Include(...)`?

My thinking is that the first way includes everything for all the elements in the target table, then filters out the ones I want, while the second one filters out the ones I want, then only includes everything for those. I don't fully understand entity framework, so is my thinking correct?

Comment: No, the code gets translated to SQL and it will use the `Include` to determine what to put in the `Select` and adding joins in the `From`.  The filter will just be part of the `Where` so the order does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework delays its querying as long as it can, up until the point where your code start working on the data. Just to prove the example:

```
var query = db.People
              .Include(p => p.Cars)
              .Where(p => p.Employer.Name == "Globodyne")
              .Select(p => p.Employer.Founder.Cars);
```

With all these chained calls, EF has not yet called the database. Instead, it has kept track of what you're trying to fetch, and it knows what query to run **if** you start working with the data. If you never do anything else with `query` after this point, then you will never hit the database.

However, if you do any of the following:

```
var result = query.ToList();

var firstCar = query.FirstOrDefault();

var founderHasCars = query.Any();
```

Now, EF is *forced* to look at the database because it cannot answer your question unless it actually fetches the data from the database. At this point, **not before**, does EF actually hit the database.

For reference, this trigger to fetch the data is often referred to as "enumerating the collection", i.e. turning a query into an actual result set.

By deferring the execution of that query for as long as possible, EF is able to wait and see if you're going to filter/order/paginate/transform/... the result set, which could lead to EF needing to return less data than when it executes every command immediately.

---

This also means that when you call `Include`, you're not actually hitting the database, so you're not going to be loading data from items that will later be filtered by your `Where` clause, **if** you didn't enumerate the collection.

Take these two examples:

```
var list1 = db.People
              .Include(p => p.Cars)
              .ToList()                     // <= enumeration
              .Where(p => p.Name == "Bob");

var list2 = db.People
              .Include(p => p.Cars)
              .Where(p => p.Name == "Bob")
              .ToList();                    // <= enumeration
```

These lists will eventually yield the same result. However, the first list will fetch data *before* you filter it because you called `ToList` before `Where`. This means you're going to be loading all people and their cars in memory, only to then filter that list in memory.

The second list, however, will only enumerate the collection when it already knows about the `Where` clause, and therefore EF will only load people named Bob and their cars into memory. The filtering will happen on the database before it gets sent back to your runtime.

---

You did not show enough code for me to verify whether you are prematurely enumerating the collection. I hope this answer helps you in determining whether this is the cause of your performance issues.

> `database.Include(...).Where(...)` and I'm wondering if that is different than `database.Where(...).Include(...)`?

Assuming this code is verbatim (except the missing db set) and there is nothing happening inbetween the `Include` and `Where`, the order does not change the execution and therefore it is not the source of your performance issue.

I generally advise you to put your `Include` statements before anything else (i.e. right after `db.MyTable`), as a matter of readability. The other operations depends on the specific query you're trying to construct.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times order of clauses will not make any difference
`Include` statement tells to SQL `Join` one table with another
While `Where` will results in.. yes, SQL `Where`

When you do something like `database.Include(...).Where(...)` you are building IQueryable object that will be transleted to direct SQL after you try to access it like with `.ToList()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` and those queries are already optimized

So if you still have performance issues - you should use profiler to look for bottlenecks and maybe consider using stored procedures (those could be integrated with EF)